# Remote IIS MVC App and local SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf-data-services

I am trying to find code examples of:
1. Remote MVC App on IIS
2. Data is on the customers SQL Server and on the windows domain they are using their web browser from.

I have a MVC app that works well with IIS and SQL Server being on the same domain.

However, I am trying to figure out how to extend the MVC App to multiple customers by hosting the site on a remote IIS server and having the remote MVC application on IIS query the customers SQL Server database.

I am comfortable with MVC, Entity Framework, & SQL Server but have had a hard time finding examples for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly change the connection string of your application to work with any remote SQL Server instance you please.   Obviously being outside the domain poses some additional challenges and security risks that you should consider, however, to get them talking to each other you can simply specify the server address in your connection string like so:

```
Data Source=192.168.10.1,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

The Network Library parameter forces the use of TCP/IP as a network protocol.  Note that the customer will have to set up a SQL Server Authentication user on their database to simplify this scenario - using a trusted connection will be impossible unless you integrate your Windows domains, which could be a significant amount of work for little benefit.